# Nested foreach array loop in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, nested

I have for each loop return an array

```
<?php foreach( get_uf_repeater( 'clients' ) as $document_files ): extract( $document_files ) ?>
<div class="ui-grid-a my-breakpoint">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="<?PHP echo $website_url ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $project_image ?>" title="Project image" /><div><?php echo $project_detailes ?></div></a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><a href="<?PHP echo $website_url ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $project_image ?>" title="Project image" /><div><?php echo $project_detailes ?></div></a></div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

how can i jump to the next array for the second line "" instead of displaying the same of the first one, I assume I need nested loop but didnt know how do it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/array_chunk)

```
<?php foreach (array_chunk(get_uf_repeater( 'clients' ), 2, true) as $array) { ?>
    <div class="ui-grid-a my-breakpoint">
        <?php foreach($array as $document_files) { ?>
            <?php extract( $document_files ); ?>
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="<?PHP echo $website_url ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo $project_image ?>" title="Project image" /><div><?php echo $project_detailes ?></div></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```